# Take a table with a quantity field, or a count of items, and make unique rows for each, dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table like this

```
 ItemsWithQuantity
 =================
 ID     Quantity
 ---------------
 x      4
 y      7
```

I want to built a view or query that turns it into this

```
ID
x
x
x
x
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
```

To basically un-count them, and get a unique row for every quantity.

What's the best way to do this dynamically, in MS SQL 2005 or 2008

Comment: Do you have a table sequences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
SELECT iq.ID FROM ItemsWithQuantity iq
INNER JOIN master..spt_values n ON iq.Quantity > n.number AND n.type = 'p'
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d24bd/1)**

This is using `master..spt_values` system table for numbers, which is a pretty safe but still *undocumented* feature. If you are unsure about using it, you can create your own Numbers table that will just list numbers, or create CTE on the fly:

```
WITH CTE_Numbers AS
(
    SELECT MAX(Quantity) AS Number FROM dbo.ItemsWithQuantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT number - 1 FROM CTE_Numbers
    WHERE number >=1
)
SELECT iq.ID FROM ItemsWithQuantity iq
INNER JOIN CTE_Numbers n ON iq.Quantity > n.number
ORDER BY ID
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d24bd/2)**

Answer (score 1):

Create a numbers table first (`(ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)`) with numbers from 1 to 1m).

Then the query becomes more easy:

```
SELECT tab.ID
FROM ItemsWithQuantity tab
CROSS APPLY (
 SELECT ID FROM Numbers WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND Quantity
) x
ORDER BY tab.ID
```

`CROSS APPLY` reads like "for each outer row, join the following rows". In our case we are joining `Quantity` inner rows to each outer row.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do it with looping.  No extrnal tables or cross-table references needed.

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @counter INT
CREATE TABLE ##tempTable(
    ID INT
)
WHILE @i<=(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ItemsWithQuantity)
BEGIN
    SET @counter=(SELECT QuantityFROM(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) RowNumber, * FROM ItemsWithQuantity) a
    WHERE RowNumber=@i)
    WHILE @counter>=0 BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ##tempTable (ID) SELECT ID FROM(
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) RowNumber, * FROM ItemsWithQuantity) a
            WHERE RowNumber=@i)
        SET @counter=@counter-1
    END
    SET @i=@i+1
END
SELECT * FROM ##tempTable
```

**UPDATE**

Using a temp table you can select it all from one query.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but that seems extremely inellegant and innefficient compared to the other two answers.  I'd be curious to see the execution plans and performance of all three compared.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Both other solutions require creating a table with a bunch of numbers (i.e. "numbers from 1 to 1m").  This is unnecessary as proposed by my solution.